# Parameterizing Asymmetric Set in MDX?

Tags: ssas, mdx

I upgraded to SQL server 2008 R2 from 2005, and now this query is no longer working(although I don't rule out something I did being the cause). I have simplified the names/query to demonstrate the issue:

```
SELECT
  NON EMPTY
  {
        [BizDim].[County].[County]
      * [BizDim].[name].[name]
  }
  ON COLUMNS,
  {
        [Biz Line Type Dimension].[Line Number].[Line Number]
      * [Biz Line Type Dimension].[Display Name].[Display Name]
  }
  ON ROWS
  FROM [TPS Data View]
  Where (
    STRTOSET("{[BizDim].[County ID].&[16]}", CONSTRAINED)  
    ,STRTOSET("{([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x]),([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].&[x],[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].ALLMEMBERS)}")    
  )
```

Essentially this is a logical OR saying if column Corp == 'x' OR HQ == 'x' then include it in the result.  This is known as an assymmetric(sic) set.

The above gives the error:
The Tuple function expects a tuple expression for the 3 argument. A tuple set expression was used.

I can remove the STRTOSET function and it works perfectly:

```
  Where (
    STRTOSET("{[BizDim].[County ID].&[16]}", CONSTRAINED)  
    ,{([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x]),([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].&[x],[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].ALLMEMBERS)}    
  )
```

However, this is no good because the actual query is parameterized, so it must work with a STRTO* function:

```
  Where (
    STRTOSET(@Counties, CONSTRAINED)  
    ,STRTOSET(@BizTypes)  
  )
```

I have tried STRTOTUPLE and get the same error.

I could build the query dynamically but I'd rather avoid taking that risk, especially given that it worked fine before with a parameter.

So the question is, how to get this assymmetric set to work as a parameter again in SQL Server 2008 R2 SSAS?

Update:
Note that this eliminates the error by replacing the keys will ALLMEMBERS, but doesn't actually filter anything so it is useful only to show in general my syntax doesn't seem to be bad:

```
  Where (
    STRTOSET("{[BizDim].[County ID].&[16]}", CONSTRAINED)  
    ,{([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].ALLMEMBERS),([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].ALLMEMBERS)}    
  )
```

I did manage to get this working in a less dynamic way, but quite annoying.  Basically my filter would need to be divided into many different parameters because I would need a STRTOSET call for each one:

```
  Where (
    STRTOSET("{[BizDim].[County ID].&[16]}", CONSTRAINED)  
    ,{
       STRTOSET("([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x])")
      ,STRTOSET"([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].&[x],[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].ALLMEMBERS)")
    }    
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

[edited after comments]

```
  Where 
    STRTOSET("{[BizDim].[County ID].&[16]}", CONSTRAINED)  
    * STRTOSET("{([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x]),([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].&[x],[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].ALLMEMBERS)}")
```

They might be an ambiguity with the ( x, y, z ) notation which is either a tuple or a parenthesis operator; e.g., ( {}, {} ) is a crossjoin.

Perhaps you need an explicit wrapping into a set :

```
{ [BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x] }
```

Or replace:

```
([BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS,[BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x])
```

with an explicit crossjoin:

```
{ [BizDim].[Corp].[Corp].ALLMEMBERS * [BizDim].[Local].[Local].ALLMEMBERS * { [BizDim].[HQ].[HQ].&[x] } }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I updated with an explanation of the purpose of the assymetric set.  To use shorthand so you can more easily see the pattern `{(Corp.All, Local.All, HQ.Yes),(Corp.Yes,Local.All, HQ.All)}`.  This essentially says give me those where HQ.Yes OR Corp.Yes.  It's a way of emulating a logical OR across different columns.